# Android Wear Sign In

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, android-signing

I have a standalone Android Wear app which has a login for in it but I'm finding the process really difficult. I don't want to create a **mobile module** in my app to request email and password from the user. I also found [this](https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/wearos/patterns/sign-in.html#sign-in-methods) which I think explains kinda what I want to do but it doesn't guide me at all.

Do you guys know a way to request email and password from users on their phone without creating a mobile module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sign in on the phone flow is available for OAuth 2.0 apps as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/auth-wear#OAuth):

> Wear provides OAuth 2.0 support for third-party apps to authenticate a user with a web service. Considering the limited screen real estate on wear devices, Wear OS OAuth support enables standalone watch apps to complete the OAuth authentication flow via a phone. Standalone apps use a request and response URL model to authenticate a user and receive an OAuth token to access the service.

This is done by using the [`OAuthClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/authentication/OAuthClient) and [`sendAuthorizationRequest()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/authentication/OAuthClient#sendAuthorizationRequest(android.net.Uri,%20android.support.wearable.authentication.OAuthClient.Callback)) to open up a WebView on the phone to your OAuth page. The [Wear OAuth sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearOAuth) provides a full example of how this works.

Comment: The service that I'm using doesn't provide OAuth view to give me a token. It's an API where you send the pass and e-mail and returns a token and that's it. They don't provide a secure web view for third parties to use.

Comment: That's the only mechanism available for phone side authentication without a phone app. Obviously, the other approaches listed in the documentation (such as asking for the email/password on the watch or directing users to a website that they manually type in their email/password and give you a short lived code) are available.

Comment: thanks you so much. It really helps me a lot to know that those are my only options.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Is this Aldo applied when using firebase auth? I mean, trying to use oauth with firebase :s

Comment: @ianhanniballake We are stuck at this point. We tried to implement the Oauth PKCE but the redirection from Web app to Watch failed. This URI -> wear.googleapis.com/3p_auth/com.your.package.name?code=xyz did not work for other manufacturers like Samsung,Fossil etc. Anything that we are missing here? Because the companion apps are different for each manufacturer. They are not WearOS app instead Samsung wearable and it has its own deep linking. Any info would be really helpful.